# CSS ::after with ::selection?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to write a selector like this, but to no success:

```
.something::after::selection
```

Basically I am already using ::after to inject some content, namely an image.  But I want to prevent the user from being able to "select" this image and get an ugly blue back-shadow.

Normally I can prevent this with the following:

```
.something::selection
{
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

But it does not seem to combine well with ::after.

Has anyone tried this before or have a solution?

Comment: what browser? chrome seems to prevent selection by default.

Comment: I'm using chrome, but its allowing selection for me.

Comment: @corsen: Can you make a test case in http://jsfiddle.net? Also what version of Chrome are you on?

Comment: I can't reproduce in JSfiddle using just text, and I'm not sure how to use it with an image.

Comment: @corsen: Host the image somewhere and link to its URL from the fiddle's CSS pane.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FhbbV/ testcase

Answer (score 0):

No, in firefox I'm 100% sure that you can't change that effect on selected images, is system-specific, and not customizable yet

*edited

Comment: @BoltClock I've completely misunderstood the message

Answer (score 0):

To prevent images to be selected you can use following css:

```
img { 
    -o-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    user-select: none; 
}
```

Also see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhbbV/1/).

With `::after` see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhbbV/2/).